# Nested/Inner read-only properties in Python

Tags: python, attributes, decorator, nested-attributes

I would like to get this behavior where I have access to an inner property `max` specified into the class `Room`.

```
>>> r = Room()
>>> r.temperature
22.0
>>> r.temperature = 18.0
>>> r.temperature.max
30.0
>>> r.temperature
18.0
```

I would like to get this behavior with this minimal code:

```
class Room(object):    
    @inner_property('min', get_temperature_min)
    @inner_property('max', get_temperature_max)
    def temperature(self):
        '''The temperature of the room'''
        return get_temperature()
```

But currently, I only succeed to implement this behavior using this code:

```
class Room(object):
    __init_done = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature = "shadow"
        self.__init_done = True

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr is 'temperature':
            return FloatMinMax(get_temperature(),                 
                get_temperature_min(), get_temperature_max(),
                'Room temperature')
        return super(Room, self).__getattribute__(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr is not 'temperature' or self.__init_done is False:
            super(Room, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
        else:
            set_temperature(value)

class FloatMinMax(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, min_, max_, doc_):
        return super(FloatMinMax, cls).__new__(cls, value) 

    def __init__(self, value, min_, max_, doc_):
        self.__min = min_
        self.__max = max_
        self.__doc__ = doc_
        super(FloatMinMax, self).__init__()

    @property
    def min(self): return self.__min

    @property
    def max(self): return self.__max
```

How can I simplify the writing using decorators?

Comment: To clarify: is `Room.temperature.min` supposed to keep track of the lowest result of previous calls to `Room.temperature`? Or is it calling another function?

Comment: Perhaps my example was confusing. No, min and max are read-only properties that could be for instance the min and maximum temperature that can be found in the room.

Comment: However, it would be interesting that the implementation allows dynamic update of these values by registering a pointer to a function instead of a scalar value.